# Jquery event touch propagation parent to child (link)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with jquery touch event. When I use my iphone and I click on Menu1, it displays my webpage "link1".

But I want this, when I click (touch) the Menu1, it displays the link1 and link2. Then I can choose between the link1 or link2.

By default, the link 1 and 2 are hidden in my css.

```js
$('body').on('touchstart', '#b', function() {
  $('#b').hide();
  $('#c').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="a">
  <li id="b">
    <a> <strong>Menu 1 </strong> </a>
  </li>
  <li id="c">
    <a href="vv.com"> <strong> Link 1 </strong> </a>
  </li>
  <li id="c">
    <a href="vv.com"> <strong> Link 2 </strong> </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you should  consider to use nested lists.... it's the way this is usually done...

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and possibly jquery mobile

Comment: Also you have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1):

Target the `:first` LI and than you can use jQuery's `.nextAll()`

<sub>(I removed ID just for simplicity sake)</sub>

```js
$('body').on('touchstart', 'li:first', function(){
 $(this).nextAll().stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul li + li{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a><b>Menu 1</b></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="vv.com"><b>Link 1</b></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="vv.com"><b>Link 2</b></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But as you can see the effect is horrible - every LI animates on it's own, therefore, usually, how we approach this task is using nested lists:

```js
$(document).on('touchstart', 'li', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // If you need more nested lists don't propagate the click
  $(this).find("> ul").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <b>Menu 1</b> <!-- Why use <a> if it's not an anchor... -->
    <ul>          <!-- Nested list! Yey -->
      <li>
        <a href="http://vv.com"><b>Link 1</b></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://vv.com"><b>Link 2</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks Roko for your answer. I tried it but the problem is : nothing happened when I click on a link ??

Comment: I think the problem comes from the e.preventDefault();

Comment: I tried without the e.preventDefault(); and the problem still there, with a "touch device" the click event is propagated to the link. For information, I use simulation on chrome to test it but I test it also on a iphone :)

Comment: @hal try now please - I removed the click event

Comment: It is very special when I click on Menu, it displays the two links and then it is wrapped (the two links disappear) ...

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem is resolved with your answers. I made also a mistake on my code; I have had a click event on the body, that is why the event click was triggered twice.